# How can I threshold for a minimum value with MatrixPlot?

Tags: plotting, matrix

Looking at the `Options` for `MatrixPlot`, there doesn't seem to be a mechanism for lowerbound threshold - i.e. ignoring values that fall below a certain cutoff.

If my data set is very large, and I need a fast method of accomplishing this, would anyone have a recommendation?

Comment: is a rule too slow? `mp = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {40, 60}];` and `MatrixPlot[mp /. a_ /; (a < .4) -> Null]`

Comment: I'd use `Chop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To long for comment. Idea different than gpap's and rcollyer's:

```
n = 300;
s = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 5, {2, 2} -> 5, {3, 3} -> 5, {n, n} -> 5}] 
    + Table[RandomReal[], {n}, {n}];

SparseArray[
    Thread[Rule[#, s[[ ##]] & @@@ #]] &@Position[s, x_ /; x > 1, 2]
    ] // ArrayPlot
```

**Edit:**
Faster than `ReplaceAll`. Slower than `Chop` but I think this is more flexible.

Comment: @J.M. Please, do not accept so quickly :)

Comment: However, it's a good answer!

Comment: FYI: `Table[RandomReal[], {n}, {n}]` would be better written `RandomReal[1, {n, n}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really see how `Chop` is (directly) applicable unless "minimum value" means absolute value, and replacement via patterns is always going to be slower than pure numerics.  I think the *flexible* and *fast* function is [`Clip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Clip.html):

> Clip[x, {min,max}, {v<sub>min</sub>,v<sub>max</sub>}]
>   gives v<sub>min</sub> for x < min and v<sub>max</sub> for x > max.

Borrowing [Bill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1783/bill-s)'s example:

```
m = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {6, 6}];
Manipulate[MatrixPlot[Clip[m, {i, ∞}, {0, 0}]], {i, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Move the slider to change the threshold value

```
m = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {6, 6}]; 
Manipulate[MatrixPlot[Chop[m, i]], {i, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Threshold[m, i]` and `ColorRules` with `PatternTest`  (`_?(Abs@# < i &)` or `j_ /; Abs@j < i`) give the same results as `Chop[m, i]`.

```
SeedRandom[1]
m = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {6, 6}];
Manipulate[Grid[{{Labeled[MatrixPlot[Chop[m, i], ImageSize -> 300],
   Style["\nChop", 16], Top],
  Labeled[MatrixPlot[Threshold[m, i], ImageSize -> 300], 
   Style["\nThreshold", 16], Top]}, 
 {Labeled[MatrixPlot[m, ColorRules -> {_?(Abs@# <= i &) -> White}, ImageSize -> 300], 
   Style[Column[{"\nColorRules -> ", "{ _?(Abs @ # <= i&) \[Rule] White}"}, 
   Alignment -> Center], 16], Top], 
 Labeled[MatrixPlot[m, ColorRules -> {j_ /; Abs@j <= i -> White}, ImageSize -> 300], 
   Style[Column[{"\nColorRules -> ", "{j_/; Abs@j <= i \[Rule] White}"}, 
   Alignment -> Center], 16], Top]}}, Dividers -> All], 
 {{i, 4}, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

The setting `ColorRules - {_?(# <= i &) -> White}` gives the same result as `Clip[m, {i, ∞}, {0, 0}]`. `Clip` and `ColorRules` are more flexible in that they allow arbitrary conditions.

```
Labeled[MatrixPlot[m, ColorRules -> {_?(-1 <= # <= 4 &) -> White}, ImageSize -> 500], 
 Style[Column[{"\nColorRules -> ",  "{ _?(-1 <= # <= 4&) \[Rule] White}"}, 
  Alignment -> Center], 16], Top]
```

[image]